# How to allocate code xc16

Tags: microchip, xc16

I developed two programs for dsPIC33EV256GM104 processor using MPLAB X IDE and XC16 compiler.
Now I have to 'merge' the programs in one (I have to export only one HEX file) but the first program should be allocated starting from adres 0x000000 and the second starting from 0x005000.

Could you help me to solve the problem ?
Thank you very much for your help and cooperation

Regards

Comment: Check the release manifest for the last few XC16 versions,  I believe there was something improved for that kind of (bootloader related) stuff.

Comment: Try the Easy bootloader? http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=Microchip%20Easy%20Bootloader#utm_source=MicroSolutions&utm_medium=Link&utm_term=FY16Q4&utm_content=MCU16&utm_campaign=Article

Comment: Dear Marco, thank you for your help. I fixed the problem and I will post the solution as soon as possible ...